# Angular Error in turbo_modules/@angular/core@13.0.3/fesm2015/core.mjs (16:undefined) Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, typescript, stackblitz

I keep getting the following error in my code ,I Looked at other posts like ["maximum call stack size exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765791/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded) but can't quite figure out, any guidance on how to fix this error?

```
Error in turbo_modules/@angular/core@13.0.3/fesm2015/core.mjs (16:undefined)
Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

I shared the code [Maxmimum call stack size exceeded](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bjcus?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

[image]

Comment: Folks, can anyone provide in puts on what is wrong  here?

Comment: Your stackblitz app is not working.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL - how about https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bjcus?file=src/app/app.module.ts ? or https://angular-4bjcus.stackblitz.io

Comment: are you able to access the URL now?

Comment: The URL opens, but the application does not work.

Comment: when you say application doesn't work, what do you see?

Comment: are you able to open the editor URL?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the core-js version in package.json from 3.20.0 to 2.6.9 seems to fix this issue.
Apparently core-js v3 has few breaking changes that are not compatible with some libraries.

Comment: I attached the screen shot where I tried to update, install package "core-js" is missing and when I try to  install it ,it installs `"core-js": "^3.20.0",` , I downgrade in the package.json to 2.6.9 but it still installs 3.20.0 , any idea how to workaround this to install 2.6.9?